# How can I make testing on the device faster?

Tags: android, testing, device

I have an application that is approximately 40 Mb.

Whenever I test my application on my Galaxy S I9000 it takes 1-2 minutes to download and another 1-2 minutes to install.

Can I upload only the part of code that I have changed?

Comment: Not unless you split it up into several smaller Android projects that work together.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that in a 40 MB app, the majority of the space is taken up by images. One possible solution is to have your app download the images the first time it is run, instead of bundling them. This way, your apk will only contain the code and resources like the icon etc, and hence be greatly reduced in size. Also, you do not need to constantly re download the images every time you update the app.

When you publish the app, you could use expansion apks to distribute the images at the time of download, or host them on your own server and download them.

Comment: Yes. I've thinking about this but i have a quiz app with a lot of vips, football players and cartoon and i don't want to show all the images on the sd card...

Comment: You could download it and save it in your apps internal storage, but I'd recommend against it. Most phones come with very limited internal storage space, and any app taking up 40 MB of it is likely to be uninstalled very quickly.

Comment: Yes but i don't want that connecting the phone on computer the users can see my images

Comment: Then internal storage or a a custom image format that only your app can decode is your only option.